What is the '<<~' called in Ruby, how does it work?
Example:
sentence = <<~ LOTSOFWORDS
this is an example of the thing initialising a variable, how else does this work?
LOTSOFWORDS

I don't think it's the shovel operator, there's no tilde in that. I'm doing a Kata that forms string variables with it, so that much I know.
I have tried looking on Google for '<<~', 'less than less than tilde' and a few other guesses at what it's called. Any clues so I can work it out?

https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/master/syntax/literals_rdoc.html#label-Here+Document+Literals

Your example is invalid, it has to be <<~LOTSOFWORDS, i.e. without a space in-between.

I didn't downvote your question. I just wanted to point out that the syntax isn't valid in case you're wondering why it's not working.

Something related that's interesting*: puts <<~LOTSOFWORDS.upcase; this is an example; LOTSOFWORDS displays THIS IS AN EXAMPLE.   *To some.

This is known as a heredoc, more specifically a "squiggly" heredoc. You can see documentation on it here.
It's used as an elegant way to define a block of text as a multi-line string, without screwing up the indentation on the page.
Heredocs have been in the ruby language pretty much since its inception. The "squiggly" heredoc syntax (which strips whitespace to the left, meaning you can sometimes indent the code more elegantly) was added to ruby version 2.3, released in 2015.
